# 複数ノードに itamae レシピを実行する方法

Tags: itamae

調べたんですが capistorano と連携する記事はでてきたけど単独で行う記事がでてきません

itamae 自体に機能がないなら
パラメーターで台数を与えたらその台数分ホスト名だけ連番にして
レシピを適用するようなレシピをかきたいと思っています

そこで itamae コマンドラインでパラメータを与える方法はないでしょうか

```
for i in 1..node[n_api_servers]
  execute 'bundle exec itamae ssh -h api#{i}.local roles/api/default.rb -y nodes/api.#{env}.yml'
end
```

イメージではこういうレシピを書いて実行したいんですが
ここに レシピ内で（たとえば node['host_name']) で取得できる値に api#{i} という連番ホスト名のパラメーターを渡したいです
できそうなのに調べてもなかなか記事がでてこなくて…

できないなら nodes/ の設定ファイルに host_name だけ変えたものを台数分かいて

```
for i in 1..node[n_api_servers]
  execute 'bundle exec itamae ssh -h api#{i}.local roles/api/default.rb -y nodes/api#{i}.#{env}.yml'
end
```

という感じでよぶしかないでしょうか…

あるいはもっといい複数台に同一レシピを適用する方法があれば教えていただけるとありがたいです

追記：

kondate を試してみたのですが

hosts.yml に台数分の設定を用意する必要がある気がします
十分な数の設定を用意しておけば実現はできそうですがきれいじゃないので
可変個数に対応した書き方はできないでしょうか

hosts.yml に

```
api1: [api]
api2: [api]
  :
```

のようにかくかわりに ssh/config みたいに

```
api*: [api]
```

のようなことができたりしないでしょうか

Comment: 追記に対しての返答を、今の回答に追記する形で記述しました。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sonots/kondate

^ kondate という Gem があり、これは、 Ansible っぽく itamae を実行するためのツールです。

複数台のサーバーに、同じプロビジョニングを施したい場合、これは role の recipe を定義し、それに対して複数のホストを割り当てることで実現されると思っています。

複数台のホストを並列で実行するにあたっては、 README によると `bundle exec kondate itamae-role` が、今まさに質問者さんが欲しいと思っている機能であると思っています。

---

(追記をうけて)

https://github.com/sonots/kondate#host-plugin

^ 上記の、 host plugin を用いると、 host 名と role の紐付けのロジックを、自分で記述することができそうです。

自分でこの機能を使ったことはないので、うまくできるかわかりませんが、ドキュメントを読む限り、任意のホスト -> role の紐付けを定義できそうではあると思っています。

Comment: 機能的にはやりたいことができそうなんですが、あまりに記事やドキュメントがでてこないのではまったときに不安ですね…　ジェムを入れて init してみたんですが最初の host.yml の localhost: [sample] のところでどっちに何をかけばいいかいきなりつまずいたんですが、公式にも「The default uses file host plugin, and hosts.yml. The contents of hosts.yml look like below:」とかかれてるだけで、ベストプラクティスやサンプルレシピのブログを探しても kondate というキーワードではほとんどヒットないです。ベストプラクティスや入門サイト的な記事があれば誘導してもらえると助かります